# ¿Como puedo hacer que este cronometro se detenga?

Tags: java, bucles

Alguien podría ayudarme a que este cronometro en java se detenga en las horas minutos y segundos indicados por el usuario al principio del programa? El programa inicia pidiéndole al usuario horas minutos y segundos y enseguida empieza a correr un cronometro pero es infinito y no termina, gracias

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class javatime extends Thread { 
        public javatime(){
            super();
        }
        public void run() {
            Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);  
            System.out.println("Introduce las horas:");
            String horas = myObj.nextLine();  
            System.out.println("Introduce los minutos:");
            String minutos = myObj.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Introduce las segundos:");
            String segundos = myObj.nextLine();
        int nuMin=00; 
        int nuSeg=00; 
        int nuHora=00;   
            try {
                for (; ;){            
                   if(nuSeg!=59) {
                       nuSeg++;                                   
                    }else{
                        if(nuMin!=59){
                            nuSeg=00; 
                            nuMin++;
                        }else{
                                nuHora++;
                                nuMin=00;
                                nuSeg=00;           
                        }
                    }               
                System.out.println(nuHora+":"+nuMin+":"+nuSeg);
                sleep(999);
                }            
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                 System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }                 
     } 
     public static void main(String[] args) {
            javatime c=new javatime(); 
            c.start();        
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

en tu metodo main() puedes solicitar que introduzcan las horas minutos y segundos:

```
Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);  // Create a Scanner object
System.out.println("Introduce las horas:");
String horas = myObj.nextLine();  // Read user input
System.out.println("Introduce los minutos:");
String minutos = myObj.nextLine();
System.out.println("Introduce las segundos:");
String segundos = myObj.nextLine();
```

Después convertir los datos del usuario a int y utilizarlos para detener tu Thread

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que hacer un casting de los *String's* y luego hacer un if igualando la lo que va saliendo por pantalla y dentro del *if* un `break;` para salir del bucle.

```
public class javatime extends Thread {

    public javatime(){
        super();
    }

    public void run() {
       Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);  
       System.out.println("Introduce las horas:");
       String horas = myObj.nextLine();  
       System.out.println("Introduce los minutos:");
       String minutos = myObj.nextLine();
       System.out.println("Introduce las segundos:");
       String segundos = myObj.nextLine();

       int nuMin=00; 
       int nuSeg=00; 
       int nuHora=00;

       int horas1 = Integer.parseInt(horas);
       int minutos1 = Integer.parseInt(minutos);
       int segundo1 = Integer.parseInt(segundos);
   
        try {
            for (; ;){            
               if(nuSeg!=59) {
                   nuSeg++;                                   
                }else{
                    if(nuMin!=59){
                        nuSeg=00; 
                        nuMin++;
                    }else{
                            nuHora++;
                            nuMin=00;
                            nuSeg=00;           
                    }
                }               
            System.out.println(nuHora+":"+nuMin+":"+nuSeg);
            sleep(999);
            if (nuHora==horas1 && nuMin==minutos1 && nuSeg==segundo1) {
             break;
            }            
            }}catch (Exception ex) {
             System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }                 
  
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       javatime c=new javatime(); 
       c.run();       
    }

}
```